# The product of a separable metric space and a Lindelöf space need not be Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In my chinese book, it offers an example: there exist a separable metric space $X$ and a Lindelöf space $Y$, such that $X \times Y$ is not a Lindelöf space. However, the construction of this space is unclear, and I think maybe something is wrong. Does somebody know this example?

Comment: See Dan Ma's discussion [non-normal product space](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/bernstein-sets-and-the-michael-line/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces $X\,'$ and $Y\,'$ in the next-to-last paragraph of [this classic paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183525263) by E.A. Michael are respectively regular Lindelöf and metrizable, and their product is not Lindelöf. Dan Ma explains a similar example in [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/bernstein-sets-and-the-michael-line/) to his Topology Blog.